# Fighting against browsers addons intrusion like zoom images

Tags: browser, add-on, zooming

in case that you have no choice and had to do css image resize (in my case about 20% smaller than natural image size) browser addons like Hoverzoom for Google Chrome, or Thumbnail Zoom Plus for Mozilla would show popup when you hover over that images.

I want to prevent that behaviour because it totally change user experience in one my UI form.

I understand that there is options to analyse all that addons and how they works, eg. use some event (onmouseover/mouseover) steal src tag - analyse - add some layer, id, class...

Eg. inside Hoverzoom addon for Google Chrome we can find some parts like:

```
z-index:2147483647
```

or

```
$('<div id="hzImg"></div>').appendTo(document.body);
```

and temporarily solution to disable only that addon is to hide that layer with

```
#hzImg{display:none!important;}
```

but it's not way to go because there is many addons like that.

**My question is what is your opinion, or solution how to prevent all that browsers type addons to show popups when user mouse hover over css resized images?**

Thanks.

Comment: My _opinion_ is that you should not try and interfere with these addons _at all_ – after all, the user has installed them in their browser for a reason. They should be used to the kind of “user experience change” that comes with them.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for comment and I'm totally agree with you, but I had specific situation in project (intranet application) and about 15% of users had installed some kind of that addons - because "they like it when they are on Facebook".

Comment: Also there are some issues with that addons and sometimes show popup on some images, and not on others - there is no uniform behaviour. Here is [link about issues in Chrome Hoverzoom](https://code.google.com/p/hoverzoom/issues/list)